# django accessing subclasses of models

Tags: django, models, subclass

I'm using subclasses in my django-models like this:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...


class Butcher(Person):
    ...

class Driver(Person):
    ...
```

In my view i want to do certain things depending on the subclass
of the Person-class, like this:

```
def person_detail_view(request, slug):
    person = Person.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if person.butcher:
        ...

    elif person.driver:
        ...
```

But this gives me a DoesNotExist-Error when the Person is a
Driver. Is there a way to ask the Person class for its subclass?

Thanks in advance
Jacques

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way. What you can do is store the person type in your person model and in your view use that field to appropriately extract information.

Answer (score 13):

Your basic logic is sound; the problem is in how you're testing. You have to check for the presence of the attribute, not it's value. For example:

```
def person_detail_view(request, slug):
    person = Person.objects.get(slug=slug)

    if hasattr(person, 'butcher'):
        ...

    elif hasattr(person, 'driver'):
        ...
```

Comment: Why does this work exactly? For inherited models, does Django ORM build related_name structures behind the scene like so: ParentClass.Subclass?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that. `Person` model queries a different table - `appname_person`, `Butcher`, a different one and `Driver` another.

The inheritance in Django models only saves you the writing of the fields again and doesn't query multiple tables - It shouldn't either.

To achieve something to this effect you should have a `Person.type` in the db, or you should use [Generic Relations](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/), where you make `Person` to have generic relations with all of the subtypes you intend to create (without actually inheriting, and defining generic foreignkey.)

If the fields in each of those models are same, just add a `type` field to the person; or if the fields are quite different, follow the generic relations approach.

Answer (score 2):

The django-polymorphic module does actually greatly the job and is fairly simple to use.

- https://github.com/chrisglass/django_polymorphic
- https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/