# Django: using ContentType vs multi_table_inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

I was having a similar problem as in
[How to query abstract-class-based objects in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797982/how-to-query-abstract-class-based-objects-in-django)
The thread suggests using multi_table_inheritance. I personally think using content_type more conceptually comfortable (just feels more close to logic, at least to me)

Using the example in the previous link, I would just add a StelarType as

```
class StellarType(models.Model):
    """
    Use ContentType so we have a single access to all types
    """
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Then add this to the abstract base model

```
class StellarObject(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True)
    stellartype = generic.GenericForeignKey(StellarType)
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

To sync between StellarObject and StellarType, we can connect post_save signal to create a StellarType instance every time a Planet or Star is created. In this way, I can query StellarObjects through StellarType.
So I'd like to know what's the PRO and CON of using this approach against using multi_table_inheritance? I think both create an additional table in the databse. But how about database performance? how about usability/flexibility? Thanks for any of your input!

Answer (score 7):

To me, ContentType is the way to go when you want to relate an object to one of many models that aren't fundamentally of the same "type".  Like if you want to be able to key Comments to Users, Pages, and Pictures on a social network, but there's no reasonable supertype shared by those three models.  Sure you could create a "Commentable" supertype, but to me that feels more like a mixin than a fundamental type from which those three things derive.  Before ContentType came out, you would have had no choice but to invent supertypes for these kind of relations, which can get really ugly really quickly if you need to do it multiple times in the same application (lets say you also have Events, Alerts, Messages, etc., each of which can apply to a different set of models).

Multi-table inheritance makes the most sense when you want to attach attributes to the base model, such that they will be shared in all concrete models that extend from it, so that you can get polymorphic behavior.  Commentable doesn't really fit this mold, because all of that behavior can be put on the Comment model, less so on the Commentable objects.  But if you have different classes of Users that share much of the same behavior and should be aggregable, then it makes a lot more sense.

The major pro of multi-table inheritance to me is a cleaner data model, with implicit relationships and inheritance that can be taken advantage of on the Python side (polymorphism is still a bit messy though, as seen [here](http://ankhos.com/2010/01/15/django-polymorphism-mixins-vs-inheritance-models/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855358/django-accessing-subclasses-of-models)).  The major pro of ContentType is that it is more general and keeps auxiliary functionality out of your models, at the cost of a bit of a slightly less pristine schema (lots of "meta" fields on your models to define these relationships).  And for your example, you still have to rely on `post_save`, which seems unnecessarily messy/magical to me, as well.

Comment: I have the same feeling about using ContentTypes framework for things that are unrelated, but I feel a bit uncomfortable using Multi-table inheritance. Trying to be guided in the best practices world, I've read in pydanny's book (2 scoops) that multi-table is evil. The final question is: Efficiency or Elegancy?

Comment: I *love* Two Scoops, but the blanket admonition against multi-table inheritance I really don't understand. You just have to understand the queries that are going to be generated for your application and whether they represent a problem. If you can do most of your work on the supertype table, then it's especially unproblematic. I can't think of why querying a supertype table and joining to subtypes should be any any worse than doing the same for a generic ContentType table, from a performance standpoint. I can see why you'd want to avoid a really complex type hierarchy though...

Comment: I agree with you. And looking for a nice way to handle this I've just found this app (django-model-utils) that seems to be very useful: [InheritanceManager](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/managers.html)

Comment: Yep! I've used that before and it greatly reduces the pain of wrangling subclasses in multi-table inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving old thread. I think it all boils down to the lookup direction. Whether you look up all subclasses for a certain FK (multitable inheritance) or define the referenced class as a content type and look it up based on the table reference and id (contenttypes) makes no big difference in performance - hint: they both suck. I think content types is a nice choice if you want your app to be easily extendible, i.e. others can add new content types to reference against. Multitable is good if you only sometimes need the extra columns defined in extra tables. Sometimes it might also be a good idea to merge all your subtypes and make only one which has a few fields left empty most of the time.