# Instance belonging in Django Model Inheritance

Tags: python, django

What is the simpliest way to figure out does `notification` belong to `BaseNotification` or to `ExtendedNotification`?

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class BaseNotification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='notifications')

class ExtendedNotification(BaseNotification):
    pass

# usage
for notification in user.notifications.all():
    # --> here <--
```

Comment: This answer suggests `hasattr(notification, 'extendednotification')`. Does that work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855358/django-accessing-subclasses-of-models

Comment: It does! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distinguish the two by using `hasattr(notification, 'extendednotification')`. Here's an example of how to use it with a loop:

```py
for notification in user.notifications.all():
    if hasattr(notification, 'extendednotification'):
        extended_notification = notification.extendednotification
        # do stuff with the extended notification
    else:
        # do stuff with the base notification
```